# how to do web test in android with appium

Tags: android, web-testing, appium

i click the launch button in appium.exe UI without configuring it.when i run the following code,there is no preference in my android emulator.How can i launch chrome browser in android emulator with appium.

```
//setup the web driver and launch the webview app.
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "chrome");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
URL url = null;
try {
url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);

// Navigate to the page and interact with the elements on the guinea-pig page using id.
remoteWebDriver.get("http://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig");
WebElement div = remoteWebDriver.findElement(By.id("i_am_an_id"));
Assert.assertEquals("I am a div", div.getText()); 
//check the text retrieved matches expected value
remoteWebDriver.findElement(By.id("comments")).sendKeys("My comment"); 
//populate the comments field by id.

//close the app.
remoteWebDriver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is not installed on SauceLab's Android Emulators so you won't be able to launch chrome. On top of that, web testing is not supported with Appium through saucelabs.

Comment: Can you point to a SauceLabs page that shows that "web testing is not supported with Appium through saucelabs" ?

Comment: I cannot find where I found that piece of information. Please let me know if it is not true and I will take it down. I will continue to search to see if I can find it and post it here.

Comment: @JeffH I did not find the saucelabs doc about this. Instead it was an answer I got on appium's google discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appium-discuss/0VZqvR4rAoc/uyA0k_dP40EJ

Comment: I think the OP is using a local appium instance and a local android device, not saucelabs.